# How do I get a mean of different observations made in a year per country over time? Non-numeric problem

Tags: r, group-by, mean, numeric

I am doing an analysis of parliamentary data over time, with regards to percentage of women in parliament for a given year. For some years there are multiple observations due to the percentage of women in parliament having undergone developments during that year. Hence I would like to write a code that gives me:

The mean of female representation in a given year over time, then afterwards grouped by country.

My problem is that R keeps returning me with NA values and a warning saying that I have non numeric data in my dataset. However I cant seem to find this non-numeric data. I only have numbers in the percentage column. Could it be the . in 0.5 that is given me trouble?

I have tried the following codes in dplyr:

```
Newlevelgenparla <- genparla %>%
  group_by(Country, Year) %>%
  summarize(Percent_women_in_parliament = mean(`Percent Of Women in Chamber`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

And

```
Newlevelgenparla <- genparla %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarize(Percent_women_in_parliament = mean(`Percent Of Women in Chamber`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However the latter one also gives me NA, and does not group by country. So it's not what I am looking for.

I would very much appreciate any help you could give me!

Edit: Output of dput(head(genparla)):

```
structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), Region = c("ASIA", 
"ASIA", "ASIA", "ASIA", "ASIA", "ASIA"), `Election / Renewal` = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), Year = c(1965, 1965, 1969, 
1969, 1988, 1988), Month = c("July", "July", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `Chamber Type` = c("Lower", "Upper", "Lower", "Upper", "Lower", 
    "Upper"), `Chamber Total Seats` = c("210", "84", "216", "84", 
    "235", "173"), `Total women` = c("4", "0", "0", "0", "7", 
    "0"), `Percent Of Women in Chamber` = c("0.019047619047619", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0.0297872340425532", "0"), NOTES = c("First legislature of Afghanistan after the abolition of the monarchy in 1964", 
    "First legislature of Afghanistan after the abolition of the monarchy in 1964", 
    "Parliament was dissolved following a military coup d'Etat in July 1973.", 
    "Parliament was dissolved following a military coup d'Etat in July 1973.", 
    "Collapse of constitutional institutions, including Parliament, in April 1992.  A Council of Decision and Settlement or Constituent Assembly, comprising 1335 members met in December 1992 and January 1993 and elected from among its ranks a 250-member interim Assembly. Pending general elections: no available information concerning the number of women members of the Council or the interim Assembly.", 
    "Collapse of constitutional institutions, including Parliament, in April 1992.  A Council of Decision and Settlement or Constituent Assembly, comprising 1335 members met in December 1992 and January 1993 and elected from among its ranks a 250-member interim Assembly. Pending general elections: no available information concerning the number of women members of the Council or the interim Assembly."
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Hi Felipe. It seems likely that your `Percent Of Women in Chamber` column is actually a character column or factor column, even if it _looks_ numeric. If it has a percentage sign after it, then it cannot be numeric. I'm sure we could figure out how to fix the problem if we had a reproducible sample of your data. Without it, all we can do is guess. Could you include the output of `dput(head(genparla))` in your question? You might also want to [edit] your question by putting your code in a [code block] so that other users can more easily read and understand it. Good luck!

Comment: @AllanCameron First of all - thank you so much for your answer and time.
I have edited the post to contain the output of the code you wrote. 
Ill make the code a codeblock

Comment: As a test you can see that `is.numeric(genparla$\`Percent Of Women in Chamber\`)` returns `FALSE`. If you print the values in this column you can see they are quoted, which is another indication the column(s) are character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your dput, I was able to replicate the issue and this is a solution that can help you solve this. you need to first convert the Chamber Total Seats, Total women and Percent Of Women in Chamber to numeric as they are character types and then perform your summary. You can do that with dplyr like this:

```
genparla <- genparla %>%
  mutate(
    `Chamber Total Seats` = as.numeric(`Chamber Total Seats`),
    `Total women` = as.numeric(`Total women`),
    `Percent Of Women in Chamber` = as.numeric(`Percent Of Women in Chamber`)
  )
```

You can then perform your summarise operations and both should work now:

```
Newlevelgenparla1 <- genparla %>%
  group_by(Country, Year) %>%
  summarize(Percent_women_in_parliament = mean(`Percent Of Women in Chamber`, na.rm = TRUE))

Newlevelgenparla1

Newlevelgenparla2 <- genparla %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarize(Percent_women_in_parliament = mean(`Percent Of Women in Chamber`, na.rm = TRUE))

> Newlevelgenparla1
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Groups:   Country [1]
  Country      Year Percent_women_in_parliament
  <chr>       <dbl>                       <dbl>
1 Afghanistan  1965                     0.00952
2 Afghanistan  1969                     0      
3 Afghanistan  1988                     0.0149 

> Newlevelgenparla2
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   Year Percent_women_in_parliament
  <dbl>                       <dbl>
1  1965                     0.00952
2  1969                     0      
3  1988                     0.0149
```

Comment: Or more succinctly, you can do `mutate(across(\`Chamber Total Seats\`:\`Percent Of Women in Chamber\`, as.numeric))`.